# Access to the path 'C is denied.'

Tags: c#, permission-denied

I use `File.Delete` to delete a `.exe` file in the C drive. But it says I don't have access to delete it. Now I want to use `File.Delete` and `File.Move` to do it, I tried running VS with Admin rights but it didn't work.
I want to work with C drive, not another drive. Thank you
P/s: I tried the mentioned solutions with the same problem, but it didn't work for me.

```
File.Delete(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\ProgramName\FileName.exe");
File.Move(@"newFileName.exe", @"C:\Program Files (x86)\ProgramName\");
```

Comment: don't bother with VS. what if you run the output exe with admin?

Comment: There is a `"` missing at the end of line 2. Does this really compile?

Comment: because you didn’t specify the file name in arg2 in `File.Move`. Like that: `File.Move("C:\file.txt", "C\files\file.txt");`. **All** methods who work with files throw `Access to the path` if you DIDN'T specified the file name.

Comment: Windows restricts access to some secured path. you need to run as 'ADMIN' for this purpose.

Comment: Elevation required, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2818776/17034).  The Move() call is wrong, you can't use it to overwrite a directory with a file.  Fix with File.Move(@"newFileName.exe", @"C:\Program Files (x86)\ProgramName\FileName.exe");

Comment: When i run exe file with admin. Program auto close

Comment: sorry, in VS. this code is File.Move(@"newFileName.exe", @"C:\Program Files (x86)\ProgramName\");

Comment: I has try run VS or exe file build with admin. But not work, i recive notications: Access to the path 'C is denied.'when run in VS. Program auto close when run with exe file build

Comment: I has use File.Delete first, and File.Move() after

Comment: Only the installer/uninstaller should be modifying files in `%ProgramFiles%` or `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`.

Comment: @D2K: You do not need to build your app as admin, but you need to run/execute it as admin.

Comment: I has try run exe with admin, but not work

Comment: @D2K after running as admin it is showing same error as denied path to c drive ?

Comment: No, it's auto close exe

Answer (score 0):

**[How do I force my .NET application to run as administrator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator)**

Try checking out this link, your application should be running as administrator to have privilege and look for second solution which is provided by **Hassan Rahman**

I hope it will resolve your query.

Comment: This is more like a comment, or even a reason to close the question (because of lack of research).

Comment: I has try, but not work with me.

Comment: I had same issue but it was resolved by **provided link** solution.